# Is "For example, he brought it, and she stacked in the shelves?" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, comma-splices

I need to combine the following sentences into one.

> For example, he brought it.
>
> He brought it, and she stacked in the shelves.

How do I combine these? Is the following combination correct?

> For example, he brought it, and she stacked in the shelves.

Comment: "For example, he brought them and she stacked them in the shelves."

Comment: I beg to differ. It is clearly a question in grammar and nothing to do with linguistics. The perception of it being a question in linguistics may be a bias based how I have answered previous questions using methods that could be associated with a linguistic approach, but that there is a separate and distinct difference.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct to combine the two sentences the way you have. I would add "it" again in the second sentence, as "stack" requires a direct object. For complicated examples, use a colon, thus: "For example: [complicated, multiple-sentence example]."

Comment: Great answer. So with R. Daniel's suggestion your sentence would be: "For example, he brought it, and she stacked *it* in the shelves."

Comment: Hello, R. ELU is aimed at linguists, and, as the number of close-votes shows, this question is unsuitable for such a site. ELL exists to help with more basic questions. Answering them here tends to encourage further misdirected posts.